# N-dimensional Moore Curve

Tags: fractals

How do I implement an $N$-dimensional [Moore Curve](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moore_curve) in Mathematica? It is known that a Moore curve of order $P$ in N-dimensions can be made of $2^{N}$ Hilbert curves of order $P-1$ arranged on the corners of the $N$-dimensional Hypercube.

Comment: What have you tried so far? Without any starting point it's tough for us to help you.

Comment: Actually... its not so hard for us to help you... but it is against etiquette, since it shows you want us to do all the work for you.

Comment: I did something related to this 7 years ago: ["Mathematica implementation of Hilbert Curve approximations"](https://antonantonov.wordpress.com/2012/01/16/205/).